# How to disable buttons in a Lightning data Table based on parameter value in JS not based on object field value

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

I want to control my button's attribute dynamically based on the parameter value on JS.

```
<HTML>
<template if:true={preEappList}>
  <lightning-datatable
    key-field="id"
    data={preEappList}
    columns={columns}
    hide-checkbox-column="true"
    default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
    onrowaction={handleRowActions}
    >
  </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

---

```
<JS>
export default class Nb_HSPreEAppList extends LightningElement {
    editDeleteButtonDisabled = false;
    deleteButtonDisabled = false;
    currentRecordId;
    showLoadingSpinner = false;

    dateInputClass;
    @track preEappList;
    @track preEapp = PREAPP_OBJECT;

    //申込候補
    @track columns =  [
        {
            label: '編集',
            type: 'button-icon',
            initialWidth: 25,
            typeAttributes: {
                name: 'edit',
                label:'',
                iconName: 'action:edit',
                disabled: this.editDeleteButtonDisabled
            }
        },
        {
            label: '削除',
            type: 'button-icon',
            initialWidth: 25,
            typeAttributes: {
                name: 'delete',
                iconName: 'utility:delete',
                label:'',
                disabled: this.editDeleteButtonDisabled
            }
        },
        {label: 'アイテムＩＤ', fieldName: "NB_ItemId__c"},
        {label: '申込書番号', fieldName: "NB_AppDocNo__c", sortable: true},
        {label: '申込日', fieldName: "NB_AppDate__c", type: 'date', sortable: true, editable: true},
        {label: 'Fatca', fieldName: "NB_Fatca__c"},
        {label: '登録者', fieldName: "NB_ScanUserName__c"},
        {label: '拠点コード', fieldName: "NB_UnitCode__c"}
    ];
}
```

I am setting editDeleteButtonDisabled and deleteButtonDisabled in a function which are called in connectedCallback().

When it load the screen, I expect buttons in a data table are disabled or non-disabled based on editDeleteButtonDisabled or deleteButtonDisabled. It is not working. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use something like `this.editDeleteButtonDisabled`, it is fixed upon the moment of instantiation. Consider this code:

```
let helloWorld = 'hello world';
let data = { helloWorld };
helloWorld = 'goodbye world';
console.log(data.helloWorld); // prints 'hello world'
console.log(helloWorld); // prints 'goodbye world'
```

Instead, you need to set the value for each element when you want to make a change:

```
this.columns[0].typeAttributes.disabled = this.editDeleteButtonDisabled;
```

Or you can set the disabled attribute to a field, then modify the data:

```
typeAttributes: { disabled: { fieldName: 'disabled' } ... }
```

And

```
this.data[0].disabled = true;
```

Either way, you'll need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly!